# How to create a linked list structure in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have billions of documents in a collection. I'm trying to store reference next document for this particular account id.

```
{"_id": "1234", "title": "Document1", accountId:145, "next": "1236"}
{"_id": "1235", "title": "Document2", accountId:146, "next": "1238"}
{"_id": "1236", "title": "Document1a", accountId:145, }
{"_id": "1238", "title": "Document2a", accountId:146,"next": "1240"} }
{"_id": "1239", "title": "Document3", accountId:147}
{"_id": "1240", "title": "Document2b", accountId:146} }
```

**How I get documents list with limit**

Since I'll need the whole 'history' of a document including next documents I guess I'll have to perform a multitude of queries depending on the size of the list?

Any suggestions on how to create a performant index? A different structure for storing linked lists would also be interesting.